# Trouble in understanding what Ruby version I am "actually"/"effectively" running

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I am on Mac OS an I am running Snow Leopard Version 10.6.8. I am using RVM in order to manage my Ruby installations (and so to use the Ruby on Rails framework) but I am in trouble when I see some outputs in the log, mostly related to the current version in use when I get some warning/error message. That is, I previously run these commands in the terminal window:

```
$ which ruby
/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

$ rvm install 1.9.3
Installing Ruby from source to: /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
...
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/usr
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.9.3-p0 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #importing default gemsets (/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #complete

$ which ruby
/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

$ rvm use --default 1.9.3
Using /<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0

$ which ruby
/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
```

Until here it seems to be OK.

However, when I get some error like in [this question related to the DelayedJob gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683094/upgrading-to-rails-3-2-2-how-to-solve-the-undefined-method-for-syckdomaintyp), I see in the log that the system is using still `Ruby 1.9.2-p290`:

```
# Note the 'ruby-1.9.2-p290'
undefined method `send_register_email\' for #<Syck::DomainType:0x00000108e2f870>\n/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:6:in
...
```

**What is wrong? How can I solve the issue?**

Comment: How did you start the `script/delayed_job` or `rake jobs:work` of the delayed jobs handler?

Comment: @sarnold - I am in development mode, so I use `rake jobs:work`.

Comment: Did you do that from the same shell that you ran `rvm use --default 1.9.3` from? Or was it from another shell? What does that other shell think the default ruby is?

Comment: @sarnold - I correctly re-installed RVM and all its dependencies (`Phusion Passenger`, run `bundle update`, etc) in order to use Ruby on Rails. However, the DelayedJob gem still output the mentioned error with `ruby-1.9.2-p290` even if I am using `Ruby 1.9.3`.

Comment: Maybe forcibly kill the running jobs runner with `kill`? (Giant guess here that perhaps running `rake jobs:work` again might not both re-starting if an existing one is already running.)

Comment: @sarnold - Sorry, I am not experto on that command. How can I `kill` all running jobs? That is, what command I should run in the Terminal window? At this time I run just `rake jobs:clear` and `script/delayed_job stop`.

Comment: That might just clear the database table; try `ps auxw  | grep ruby` and look for Ruby processes that look like they're running the DelayedJob gem. (If you've got other active `ruby` processes, you wouldn't want to kill unrelated tasks..)

Comment: @sarnold - Nothing has changed. I killed all ruby processes and also tried to restart the machine. I get always the same error. Should I check for some configuration file on my system? Or maybe it is a bug od the DelayedJob gem? Or incompatibility of Ruby on Rails?

Comment: *BTW*: In the Activity Monitor Panel are running **8** `ruby` processes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8845/discussion-between-backo-and-sarnold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @sarnold suggests you will have to restart any long running processes such as daemons.

Another thing is that if it is running in a cron tab, make sure the cron task is running as the right user. If you set up RVM for a user, and not the system, then root, or any other user than you didn't set up RVM for, will be using system ruby.

You carefully snipped out ""

Note this can easily happen with

```
sudo rake some:task # that has to do something as root like open a low port or move a file
```

this will run as root and not do the right RVM sourcing. To fix this, there is

```
rvmsudo rake some:task
```